# social authentication for django application using javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

i need a facebook authentication in my web application which is running in a localhost(127.0.0.1:8000) but when i press the fbbutton it will give some error

I have given site url=http://127.0.0.1:8000

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

please if somebody knows the solution then kindely reply

Comment: Possibly the authentication config does not match 127.0.0.1:8000. Impossible to tell without more details

Comment: why dont you use localhost directly instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000.

Comment: in fb developer console you should have localhost url of your redirect page.bcoz it does not allow high level hosts.is only allows recognized hosts

Comment: I am trying to social authrntication for django web application in local host  using javascript i created one app in facebook developer and given http://localhost:8000 but it's not working it giving the same error.  Ijust wanted to know what to mention in the site url  of facebook for localhost using javascrip ?